# In ggplot, Is it possible to change the lines in the legend to some arbitrary color

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Suppose I have an arbitrary dataset as shown below:

```
foo <- structure(list(y = c(-2.51, -2.12, -2.03, -1.9, -1.83, -1.78, 
-1.75, -1.73, -1.67, -1.62, -1.61, -1.5, -1.47, -1.45, -1.44, 
-1.39, -1.28, -1.27, -1.19, -1.17, -1.14, -1.14, -1.13, -1.12, 
-1.07, -1.07, -1.07, -1.06, -1.06, -1.04, -1.02, -1.01, -1, -0.99, 
-0.98, -0.97, -0.95, -0.95, -0.95, -0.94, -0.93, -0.9, -0.9, 
-0.87, -0.87, -0.86, -0.84, -0.84, -0.84, -0.83, -0.81, -0.8, 
-0.77, -0.76, -0.73, -0.71, -0.71, -0.69, -0.69, -0.66, -0.66, 
-0.65, -0.65, -0.64, -0.58, -0.57, -0.55, -0.54, -0.53, -0.51, 
-0.5, -0.47, -0.47, -0.46, -0.45, -0.4, -0.4, -0.39, -0.39, -0.38, 
-0.35, -0.31, -0.3, -0.3, -0.3, -0.29, -0.27, -0.24, -0.23, -0.23, 
-0.22, -0.19, -0.18, -0.17, -0.15, -0.14, -0.14, -0.13, -0.12, 
-0.12, -0.11, -0.1, -0.08, -0.04, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.02, 
0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 0.16, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 
0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.28, 0.29, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.33, 0.34, 0.34, 0.36, 0.45, 0.51, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 
0.56, 0.56, 0.63, 0.64, 0.67, 0.67, 0.69, 0.7, 0.72, 0.72, 0.74, 
0.75, 0.77, 0.79, 0.86, 0.91, 0.95, 0.98, 1, 1.02, 1.05, 1.07, 
1.11, 1.13, 1.13, 1.14, 1.18, 1.22, 1.22, 1.23, 1.24, 1.24, 1.24, 
1.38, 1.38, 1.49, 1.59, 1.6, 1.61, 1.62, 1.69, 1.71, 1.75, 1.75, 
1.78, 1.79, 2.1, 2.23), x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), condition = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L)), .Names = c("y", "x", "condition"), row.names = c(NA, 200L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I can make a plot like the one below:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x, y, color=factor(condition))) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Suppose for whatever reason, I don't need four different lines with different colors in the legend. Instead, I want to have only one black line in the legend. However, it seems that the specifications of the actual plot (e.g., color, line type, etc) map onto the legend. So I am not sure how I can change it.

#### So my question is how can I set the legend arbitrarily: arbitrary color, line type, and text

Comment: Try `+ guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour="black")))`. Also have a look at http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf

Comment: More generally, if you want to literally construct arbitrary legends manually, **ggplot** is really not going to be a great tool for that. It is largely designed with precisely the _opposite_ intent. If you want that much control over your legends (and the fiddly work that comes with it) you will probably be happier using base graphics.

Comment: @joran True...this is something that I've come to realize today...after spending hours fiddling with various aspects of `ggplot`...

Comment: @Alex, if you have a chance have a look at Winston Chang's excellent [R Graphics Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023135.do). Starting on page 225 you will find almost 20 pages of manipulating legends in ggplot addressing all your questions concerning arbitrary color, line type, and text .I can not see how this is more complicated than using base graphics quite the contrary, I find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat a bit - fake up the legend with `ggplot()` and use `grid.arrange()` to put them together:

[image]

```
#pre-reqs
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

#make a blank background theme
blank_theme<-theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
                   axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                   axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                   axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                   axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                   axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                   legend.position="none",
                   panel.background=element_blank(),
                   panel.border=element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
                   plot.background=element_blank())

#main plot, without legend
g.plot<-ggplot(foo, aes(x, y, color=factor(condition))) + geom_line() + theme(legend.position="none")

#legend based on tile, arc and title
g.legend<-qplot(0.5,0.5,geom="blank") + blank_theme +
  geom_tile(aes(1,1),fill="lightgrey", color="black") + 
  geom_text(aes(x=1,y=2,label="TITLE"),size=3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.7,xend=1.3,y=1,yend=1)) +
  coord_fixed(1,c(0.4,1.6),c(0.4,2.3))

#use grid arrange to layout
grid.arrange(g.plot, g.legend, widths=c(0.9, 0.1), ncol=2, nrow=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x, y, group=factor(condition), color="red")) + geom_line()
```

With `group=factor(condition)` you make sure that the lines for the different conditions are drawn, with `color="red"` you set the color of all lines. Excluding the `color="red"` part will result in black lines.
[image]

For further styling tips for the legend, see the [online R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/).